# How to dump only the MySQL database structure?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to take dump of MySQL database structure using the following commands:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p databasename > dumpfile.sql
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p database databasename > dumpfile.sql
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -P 3306 -p databasename > c:\dumpfile.sql
```

What is wrong with them? Where should I get this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump is a command i invoke at the shell prompt, not within the mysql client environment.

```
mysql> exit

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin>mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

this works for me.

[useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281026/error-106442000-while-trying-to-execute-mysqldump-command)

Comment: This is MySQL dump from PHP admin not normal MySQL dump.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `MySQLdump` and specify  location will be inside the directory you specified for example:

```
mysqldump  -u root -d  -P port -p password databasename > c:\dumpfile.sql
```

the dump location will be inside your machine under C drive

but if you did not specify  the directory the dump location will by inside MySQL\bin

```
mysqldump -u root -d -P port -p password databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: `mysql> mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -P 3306 -p databasename > c:\dumpfile.sql`...not working this

Comment: -p stand for password you need to add the password in-order to make it work, if you don't have password for MySQL remove -p and give it a try

Comment: still not working

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: no error is coming

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a directory under your C: drive.

```
mkdir dumps
```

Then issue the mysqldump command and specify the new location.

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -p databasename > C:\dumps\dumpfile.sql
```

You can navigate with the GUI and check if the file was created in that directory.